# Regarding scope of some variable

Tags: c#

Can I use the "str" named variable in the code below outside of try block the way I have?

I am a bit confused.

```
if ()
{
 try
 {
  String str;
 }
 catch
 {
  //exception
 }
 String result=str; // Will this work ??? It's inside of IF block only.
}
```

Comment: You will need to be a little bit clearer than this. You are not making a lot of sense

Comment: Can you please read your code and fix it. you don't declare a `var` variable anywhere.

Comment: Where did `var` come from?  You have `str` in your TRY section.

Comment: I think your quesiton is wrong, should the last line be String result=str ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always declare variables before the try catch block and initialise it to null or default value, whichever is applicable.

Doesn't matter if you'll use variable in try or catch or finally or won't use it at all. It will save you trouble in future and it will improve the readibility of your code.

```
public void processSomeRequest()
{

   string firstVariable = null;
   string secondVariable = null;
   int someInt = 0;

   try
   {
       // Initialise variables
       firstVariable = "test";
       secondVariable = "blah";

       // Process request code
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       logException(e);
       throw;
   }

}
```

Basic example, but you know what you are going to work with from very start. Unused variables will be highlighted.

Comment: declare BEFORE try block ?? wont the variables be outside of try block's scope then ?? Howz that gonna wok..I mean to use a variable..I need to declare is inside of the block ..right?

Comment: *declare it*..sry for the typo

Comment: sry for the dumb comment..got it..thnx

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you wanted to have string result = str; ... no it wont work.

Comment: yeah it was str only..hv editted it...just wondering why VS is not showing compile time error

Answer (score 1):

No, anything you declare inside the `try` block can only be used within the scope of the `try` block.

The only way to access a variable you use in the `try` block somewhere else would be to declare it before the `try` block.

Comment: @user: because you have not used `str` elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is can you reference a variable that's defined in a try block from outside the try block. The answer is no, however you can reference a variable defined outside the try block and set within the try block as follows:

```
string myVar;

try
{
   myVar = "something";
}
catch {}

// now you can set otherVar to "something"
string otherVar = myVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  The declaration is limited to the try block only.  You won't even be able to use it in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable within a scoped block (anything within `{}`), it can only be using within it.

Answer (score 0):

No, declare your "str" outside of the try {} block.